# How to set different color scheme for console in PhpStorm?

Tags: console, phpstorm, color-scheme

I use light color scheme for my editor:

[image]

and I'm trying to set dark color scheme for console:

[image]

After "Apply" button click I see this message:

[image]

I click "No", but my main editor color scheme is changing:

[image]

How to set these settings separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I click "No", but my main editor color scheme is changing:

That's not what that message meant.

There are 2 different styling options is this IDE:

1. "Color Scheme" (the one that you have edited) that affects Editor area/console and few other related elements;
2. and then there is actual GUI Theme .. which works with actual windows/buttons/check boxes/progress bars etc.

That message asked if you wish to change your GUI Theme as well ... which you did not .. as you still have ordinary editor tab colors etc (as per your last screenshot).

---

Now: the Color Scheme -- it does not work like what you have tried to do -- you can use only **one** Color Scheme **at a time** (one scheme covers all elements).

You cannot set "use PHP/HTML/whatever colors from this scheme and Console colors from this one".

If you wish to change colors only for Console ... you have to do this by changing these colors in current scheme manually.

Comment: Thanks! Now I created my own scheme (using "save as" button) with colors that I wanted.

Comment: Do you know how to change file and folder icons? I like Material UI icons, but don't like dark theme.

Comment: It's not customizable from user end (I mean -- no GUI) -- only via custom plugin that can load different icons during runtime (there are 3 or so Theme plugins already available -- maybe one of them allows to apply icons only)